# How to create nonlinear power-law spaced vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, function

I'm trying to create a power law (x<sup>3</sup>) contour plot in the code. 
Please look at the following question and the accepted answer: (logarithmic vector :`temp`)

[How to create nonlinear spaced vector in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139451/how-to-create-nonlinear-spaced-vector-in-matlab)

I want a power law vector for `temp` instead of logarithmic.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can choose your spacing based on any function. For instance, here `y` is a function of `x`. But `x` is not linearly spaced. Instead, it is a function of another variable, `t`, which is linearly spaced. *x(t)* defines the spacing:

```
t = 0:.02:2;
x = @(u) u.^3; % or any other function
y = @(u) sin(u); % or any other function
figure; plot(x(t), y(x(t)), '*b')
```

With this output:

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer, you could [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Otherwise, you are welcome to ask for any clarification.